# Looking for a tool that can execute Dynamic Partitions operations

Tags: adb, fastboot, partitions

For managing dynamic partitions, there are [a number of operations](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/dynamic_partitions/nonab#update-flow) such as `resize`, `remove`, `add_group` ...

When flashing a Rom, these commands are listed in `dynamic_partitions_op_list` file (with Rom file) and are being executed with updater-script file of Rom;

An example of content of `dynamic_partitions_op_list` file:

```
# Add group qti_dynamic_partitions with maximum size 7588834592
add_group qti_dynamic_partitions 7588834592
# Add partition system to group qti_dynamic_partitions
add system qti_dynamic_partitions
# Grow partition system from 0 to 2344250624
resize system 2344250624
```

The execution of `dynamic_partitions_op_list` operations in updater-script file:

```
assert(update_dynamic_partitions(package_extract_file("dynamic_partitions_op_list")));
```

Right now for managing dynamic partitions (for example resizing one), I put my custom `dynamic_partitions_op_list` file into a flashable zip (with updater-script file);

Is there any way/tool that can execute those operations without the need for creation of a custom `dynamic_partitions_op_list` file and flashable updater-script file? (I mean something that could be executed via `adb` or `fastboot`)

Comment: what is wrong with unofficial tools like super_image_dumper?

Comment: using that tool, one first have to take a full dump of super partition and later on modify it. What I'm looking for is some type of command line tool that could for example resize a partition within super (e.g: `adb shell tool resize system 2500MB`)

Comment: understand but what is the benefit? resize system usually is not a daily task